# How to escape slashes that are to be part of the string?

Tags: java, string

Im having difficulty finding a way to escape these quotes,

```
String key = StringUtils.substringBetween(html, "class=\"category_keyword\"", "&gt;");
```

Specifically this part:

**`"class=\"category_keyword\""`**

How the heck do I escape the quotes in (**\"category_keyword\"**) while keeping the slashes?

Those slashes are not for escaping they are part of the string. Yet when i add another (to escape the quote), Eclipse thinks I'm escaping the slash next to it.

Im sorry if this is a bit confusing, let me know if i could be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do: `\\\"category_keyword\\\"`

`\\` => You are escaping the slash `\`

`\"` => You are escaping the quote `"`

```
public class Class{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        System.out.println(" \\\"Ferrari\\\" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the slashes but escape the quotes:

```
\\\"category_keyword\\\"
```